# Python3 check if exact string match in the event dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, lambda

I have the following event body (dictionary) coming in to the lambda function and I do something like the below:

```
{
  "test-report": {
    "url": "http://example.com",
    "original-policy": "default-src 'none'; style-src example.com; report-uri /_/test-reports"
  }
}

if 'test-report' in event['body']:
    try:
        do something here
```

My problem is I want to check `test-report` in the first object in the dictionary. If that does not match, I don't want the function to do anything. However, as you can see  `**test-report**s` is also present under `original-policy` values, which I don't want to consider for my if statement.

Comment: To reproduce the issue, the sample code is missing the `body`. Please update the response event

Comment: The `in` operator for a dictionary just tests whether there's a matching key, it doesn't go deeper. I don't see the problem.

Comment: `'test-report' in event['body']` checks whether `event['body']` has a key `'test-report'` (assuming `event['body']` is a dictionary)

Comment: When you use `in` on a dictionary, it only checks the _keys_; it does not check _values_.  So this should work exactly as you want.  (However, presumably you are having some sort of problem or else you would not have posted this question, so it seems you need to explain more...)

Comment: Thanks everyone. Yes, the body is a dictionary. I updated the question.

Comment: As already answered by @YevhenKuzmovych, the condition is checked for the `test-report` of the dict keys only. It will not check for the `test-report` inside the key `original-policy`. Your approach is right.

Answer (score 0):

Well, i asume, that by first objet you mean the key in the dictionary, as they are not ordered.
If so, try :

```
  if 'test-report' in event['body'].keys():
  try:
do something here
```

Comment: This is equivalent code to OPs

Comment: If event['body'] is a dictionary then treating it as an iterator by default only checks the keys, so this would be equivalent to the code provided in the question. If you want key/value pairs in Python you have to use dict.items()